# msvc 15.3.1 compiler issue

Tags: visual-c++, visual-c++-2017

I have found a strange behavior (probably an issue) while trying to compile a simple application with MS VC 15.3.1 (after applying VC 2017 Upgrade 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

// compiles if commenting out the line below
#include <vector>
#include <list>

class A
{
    std::string s;
    public:
    A(const std::string& str) : s(str)
    {
    }

    A(A&& other)
    {
        // compiles if changing std::swap<std::string>() to std::swap()
        std::swap<std::string>(s, other.s);
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{   
    return 0;
}
```

the compiler emits error :

```
1>d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503\include\vector(2131): 
error C2039: '_Alloc': is not a member of 'std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char>>'
```

This code compiles without any issues with VC 15.2, VS2015 and VS2013 toolsets.

Comment: It seems suspicious that `<vector>` gets included from a subdirectory named `14.11.25503`, rather than something with `15` in it. I'd check include paths carefully.

Comment: You are trying to call a wrong `swap`. [The overload that works on `std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/swap2) takes three template parameters, not one. Do not attempt to provide explicit template arguments - allow overload resolution to do its thing. Better still, make it `A(A&& other) : s(std::move(other.s)) {}`

Comment: d:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio\2017\enterprise\vc\tools\msvc\14.11.25503 is what VS Update 3 installs - VS 2017 15.3.1 toolset. Whatever move ctor is using std::swap in a wrong way, I think "#include <vector>" should not influence compilation status. Also, changing move ctor to move assignment operator leads to the same compilation error.